# dual sim mobile data usage monitor

Tags: android

I have a dual sim phone, where one sim card is for a standard plan with calls, sms, and a limited data transfer; exceeding that transfer incurs extra fees. The other card provides unlimited data transfer (no calls etc) but I need to type a captcha for it to work for an hour, another hour, another captcha.

The unlimited data one is good for watching videos or browsing the net, downloads, updates etc, but if I want to have email notifications 24/7 I must switch to the limited one - and watch my usage, and remember to switch again before any heavier use.

There are quite a few mobile data monitoring apps, but all I found so far tend to bundle usage from both cards into a single pool, making them useless in determining if I'm approaching the limit on one cards. Can you recommend one that can measure usage per card? A widget for the home screen would be a plus but isn't necessary.

Comment: Doesn't *Settings › Data usage* do that per SIM? I've got a DualSIM as well (though I currently use it with one SIM only), and it has separate tabs for each SIM in that place.

Comment: @Izzy: My Settings menu doesn't have such item.

Comment: You don't have "data usage" in settings – or no separate tabs in data usage?

Comment: @Izzy: No "Data usage" in settings. Might be a MIUI quirk - that's a Xiaomi phone. They differ from most "western" models somewhat.

Comment: First time I hear a device doesn't have that item in settings. And I see no reason why Xiaomi should have removed that. Ah, another Samsung – they've just moved that to another place: [How to use the Data usage feature on your Xiaomi device?](http://webcazine.com/11931/how-to-use-the-data-usage-feature-on-your-xiaomi-device/) Can you check if that helps you? Screenshots indicate it supports DualSIM. Also see: [How to use ''Data Usage & Restrict App Data Usage'' Settings in MIUI 6.](http://en.miui.com/thread-115521-1-1.html)

Comment: @Izzy: Oooh, so that's where they hid it! Thanks!

Comment: Anytime! So does this match your requirements? I'd then make it an answer you can accept, so other readers see it has a solution :)

Comment: @Izzy: yep, that works. And it provides way more thorough monitoring than most apps that I found. It definitely doesn't look&feel like part of the Settings too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Data Usage Monitoring, Android has an integrated tool usually found in *Settings › Data Usage* – though some manufacturers who put their own UI on top (like Samsung with its *TouchWiz* or, in your case, *MIUI* on Xiaomi devices) tend to place things in different locations.

A little Google-Fu brought up an article named [How to use the Data usage feature on your Xiaomi device?](http://webcazine.com/11931/how-to-use-the-data-usage-feature-on-your-xiaomi-device/), which describes where MIUI has placed the "Data Usage" utility: It's inside another app called "Security", where you need to tap its button.

[image: Security app] [image: data limit] [image: data usage]
<sup>MIUI's data usage tool inside the security app (source: [webcazine](http://webcazine.com/11931/how-to-use-the-data-usage-feature-on-your-xiaomi-device/); click images for larger variants)</sup>

This tool splits things by SIM card slot, as you might guess by the second screenshot (end of the title bar: "(SI…" most likely is "SIM1" or "SIM2") and are definitely told by the third (second line: "(SIM 1)"). As approved by OP, it fits all requirements even better than expected.

I don't know if it has a widget, but you can create a shortcut at least:

[image: shortcut]